# What is the difference between using process substitution vs. a pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution

I came across an example for the using `tee` utility in the `tee` info page:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/dvd.iso | tee >(sha1sum > dvd.sha1) > dvd.iso
```

I looked up the `>(...)` syntax and found something called "process substitution". From what I understand, it makes a process look like a file that another process could write/append its output to. (Please correct me if I'm wrong on that point.)

How is this different from a pipe? (`|`) I see a pipe is being used in the above example—is it just a precedence issue? or is there some other difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no benefit here, as the line could equally well have been written like this:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/dvd.iso | tee dvd.iso | sha1sum > dvd.sha1
```

The differences start to appear when you need to pipe to/from *multiple* programs, because these can't be expressed purely with `|`. Feel free to try:

```
# Calculate 2+ checksums while also writing the file
wget -O - http://example.com/dvd.iso | tee >(sha1sum > dvd.sha1) >(md5sum > dvd.md5) > dvd.iso

# Accept input from two 'sort' processes at the same time
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

They're also useful in certain cases where you for any reason can't or don't want to use pipelines:

```
# Start logging all error messages to file as well as disk
# Pipes don't work because bash doesn't support it in this context
exec 2> >(tee log.txt)
ls doesntexist

# Sum a column of numbers
# Pipes don't work because they create a subshell
sum=0
while IFS= read -r num; do (( sum+=num )); done < <(curl http://example.com/list.txt)
echo "$sum"

# apt-get something with a generated config file
# Pipes don't work because we want stdin available for user input
apt-get install -c <(sed -e "s/%USER%/$USER/g" template.conf) mysql-server
```

Comment: So, it's effectively like saying `> filename.ext` or `< filename.ext`, but a process instead of a file?

Comment: Yes. `echo <(date)` and `cat <(date)` give a good clue as to how this works.

Comment: There's an important difference from a redirect: it doesn't redirect anything, instead it passes the name of the pipe (actually something like "/dev/fd/63") to the command as an argument, and expects the command to open that "file" and read/write it. The `echo <(date)` example @thatotherguy gave should show this, because it just prints the filename rather than reading from it.

Answer (score 3):

Another major difference is the propagation of *return values* / *exit codes* (I'll use simpler commands to illustrate):

**Pipe:**

```
$ ls -l /notthere | tee listing.txt
ls: cannot access '/notthere': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
0
```

-> exit code of `tee` is propagated

**Process substitution:**

```
$ ls -l /notthere > >(tee listing.txt)
ls: cannot access '/notthere': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

-> exit code of `ls` is propagated

There are of course several methods to work around this (e.g. `set -o pipefail`, variable `PIPESTATUS`), but I think it's worth mentioning since this is the default behavior.

---

Yet another rather subtle, yet potentially annoying difference lies in *subprocess termination* (best illustrated using commands that produce lots of output):

**Pipe:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tar --create --file /tmp/etc-backup.tar --verbose --directory /etc . 2>&1 | tee /tmp/etc-backup.log
retval=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
(( ${retval} == 0 )) && echo -e "\n*** SUCCESS ***\n" || echo -e "\n*** FAILURE (EXIT CODE: ${retval}) ***\n"
```

-> after the line containing the pipe construct, all commands of the pipe have already *terminated* (otherwise `PIPESTATUS` could not contain their respective exit codes)

**Process substitution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tar --create --file /tmp/etc-backup.tar --verbose --directory /etc . &> >(tee /tmp/etc-backup.log)
retval=$?
(( ${retval} == 0 )) && echo -e "\n*** SUCCESS ***\n" || echo -e "\n*** FAILURE (EXIT CODE: ${retval}) ***\n"
```

-> after the line containing the process substitution, the command within `>(...)`, i.e. `tee` in this example, *may still be running*, potentially causing desynchronized console output (SUCCESS / FAILURE message gets mixed in with still flowing `tar` output) **[*]**

---

**[*]** Can be reproduced on the framebuffer console, but does not seem to affect GUI terminals like KDE's Konsole (likely due to different buffering strategies).